# Depending of clicked button to open different activity android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

On my start(home) screen I have 3 buttons. `Button_1`, `Button_2` and `Button_3`. They are all open same `Activity B`. So here I need depending on which button is clicked on home screen to open different `Activity C` after second activity. I can make it with 2 buttons but when I try with third button with `elseif` it doesn't work properly. Here is how I trying it.
Home screen

```
Button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isButtonClicked",true);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});

Button_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("button", true);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
Button_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isButtonClicked",false);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Here is `SecondActivity`

```
boolean isButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isButtonClicked",false); 
boolean button = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button",true); 
            if(isButton) 
            { 
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class); 
                newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position); 
                newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer); 

                newActivity.putExtra("text", MyArrList.get(position).get("text").toString()); 
                newActivity.putExtra("name", MyArrList.get(position).get("name").toString()); 
                startActivity(newActivity); 
            } 
            else if (button)
            { 

                Intent newActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FourthActivity.class); 
                newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position); 
                newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer); 
                newActivity.putExtra("id", MyArrList.get(position).get("id").toString());
                startActivity(newActivity); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FifthActivity.class); 
                newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position); 
                newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer); 
                newActivity.putExtra("id", MyArrList.get(position).get("id").toString());
                startActivity(newActivity); 
            }
```

As you can see after second activity which is same for all 3 buttons then I want to load different. If I put it just with `if{}else{}` i.e. for two buttons is working good. But now I get same result on `Button_2` and `Button_3`.

Comment: `same result on button 2 and 3`... which block ?

Comment: `elseif{}else{}` ... it is open `FifthActivity.class` for both buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found that:

```
boolean button = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button",true);
```

should always return `true`. As it has a default value set to `true`. So your `elseif` will work always..if `Button_1` is not clicked!

Fix:

```
boolean button = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button",false);
```

Comment: Ok, how can I fix this?

Comment: change that `true` to `false` for default value.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
boolean button = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button",true);
```

So in 2nd and 3rd option this value will be true, so this is the reason of it.

Change to:

```
boolean button = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button",false);
```

and should be ok.